# While Loop with Break Statement in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

why do I keep receiving Stopped - and it does not exit the while loop like in the example code below?

After break this will not executed
Stopped
After break this will not executed
Stopped
After break this will not executed
Stopped
After break this will not executed
Stopped

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "computername" -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {Stop-Service -Name spooler}
$i=7
while($i -le 10){
$service=Invoke-Command -ComputerName "computername" -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -Name spooler| %{$_.Status}}
if($service -eq "Stopped"){
Write-Output "Break command is going to run now"
Break
}
Write-Output "After break this will not executed"
Write-Host $service
$i++
}
```

but when I use the example:

```
$i=5
while($i -le 10){
if($i -eq 8){
Write-Output "Break command is going to run now"
Break
}
Write-Output "After break this will not executed"
$i++
}
```

I receive the response I needed - where it breaks as desired in this example code.  You receive the single line "Break command is going to run now" once.

After break this will not executed
After break this will not executed
After break this will not executed
Break command is going to run now

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70974060/15339544  You need to refer to `$service.Value` due to serialization

Comment: but this is returning Stopped ---> $service=Invoke-Command -ComputerName "DCQWDBS554" -Credential $credentials -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -Name spooler| %{$_.Status}}After breaking it moves to execute four times the after break this will not be executed
Stopped --- four times
which then breaks but then continues to repeat --

Comment: That's because `Write-Host` is doing a `ToString` on the serialized object, which will return the actual value (`Stopped`). Just try `if($service.Value -eq "Stopped"){` or `if($service.ToString() -eq "Stopped"){`

Comment: If the linked duplicate doesn't answer your question @ me and I'll reopen your question.