# PowerShell Invoke-Command shows different output than running the same command locally

Tags: powershell

Using PowerShell, if I run this command on my local computer, the output is "Running"

```
(Get-Service -Name Spooler).Status
```

If I run the same command inside an Invoke-Command script block, to get the status of the service on a remote computer

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.131.173.71 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {(Get-Service -Name Spooler).Status}
```

the output is

```
PSComputerName RunspaceId                           Value  
-------------- ----------                           -----  
10.131.173.71  5f1b9d02-4c60-47a9-b783-01fa89eb1d58 Running
```

How can I get the same output with the second command? (Running)

Comment: Wrap the whole thing in parentheses again and use `.Value`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. You don't get the same value when remoting because the [`Status` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.status?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-serviceprocess-servicecontroller-status) is an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) and it gets de-serialized that way. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70973590/powershell-if-is-not-working-windows-services-checks/70974060#70974060) for more details.

```bash
[ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus] (
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.131.173.71 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
        [int] (Get-Service Spooler).Status
    }
)
```